# Convert PDF to png like Xcode does during compilation

Tags: xcode, pdf, image-conversion, sips

I have some assets in my iPhone app which are in PDF. Xcode automatically converts them to pngs of appropriate size. However, I need to include these in my android app. So, I want to take the PDF and produce 2 variants of pngs for my Android app.

I was trying to convert PDF to png using `sips`. Unfortunately, I cannot control the resulting size. I was trying to achieve this using the `dpiHeight`/`dpiWidth` parameters, but they seem to have no effect.

Two lines below produce the png of exact same size and it is driving me crazy:

```
sips -s dpiHeight 300 -s dpiWidth 300 -s format png TS4612.pdf --out out.png
```

and

```
sips -s dpiHeight 150 -s dpiWidth 150 -s format png TS4612.pdf --out out.png
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! If anyone knows how to achieve what I want using other methods I am up for suggestions. Xcode does it somehow so I am pretty sure that I should be able to also do it on my mac.

## Update

It is possible to obtain correct size using ImageMagick command. For example:

```
convert -density 576 -quality 100% TS4612.pdf -resize 25% out.png
```

However, the resulting quality is not great. If I compare it to the output of `sips` (matching the resolution) then I do notice that `sips` produces image of higher quality. If only I could control its density (hence size)...

Comment: -quality 100 is not typical of png compression in Imagemagick and should come after reading the pdf and after the resize.  See http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality. If the pdf contains a raster image, then you may want to use pdfimage to extract the raster image from the vector shell

Comment: @fmw42 thanks for your input. The PDF in question contains vector graphic, not a raster image.

Comment: Will try rearranging the arguments and will get back

Comment: For ImageMagick 6, rearranging likely won't make a difference. But the -quality value should, if you use the reference I provided to pick a more optimum value. What version of ImageMagick are you using?